# Two column layout in column direction with css grid

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I'm trying to create a two-column layout with CSS grid with items flow in a column direction and I managed to create the layout but the problem is when the child items are dynamic it breaks. here's the snippet that I've tried. so basically `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);` <4> should be dynamic it should be half of the total number of items. Is there any way that I can achieve it through CSS. [Click here for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqtyzh4r/)

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with CSS-Grid - there is no "balance" functionality. You need to **know** the number of rows.

Comment: I'd suggest CSS-Columns which **does** have a "balance" option.

Comment: here is the column CSS example : https://jsfiddle.net/hLnvk2b8/ ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts  & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: @Paulie_D That makes sense. but what about the browser compatibility and if the total number of items is odd the middle item will break between the columns.

Comment: @VivekrajKR give it a try with the forked fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hLnvk2b8/1/ , that is why inline-block + width:100%; is there for the children ;) About support, see https://caniuse.com/#search=column to check it out. grid or column not supported breaks the same way, elements stack.

Answer (score 0):

examples provided in earlier comments  with [column CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) did not seem to suits your needs : https://jsfiddle.net/hLnvk2b8/ , https://jsfiddle.net/hLnvk2b8/1 .

If you want to stick to the grid flowing into column with an unknown amount of rows `Javascript` could help you update the row's amount needed.

SASS is unable to access  the document, it only compiles CSS selectors and CSS rules ,that is why you would need a script (*it can be on server side too*) to inspect the DOM:

example via javascript on browser's side :

```js
window.onload = resetgrid('2');


function resetgrid(varcol) {
  var colnum = varcol;/* how many columns do you want ? */
  var child = document.getElementById("gridrow").childElementCount;/* how many children */
  var els = child / colnum;/* how many rows could that make */
  var rows = Math.round(els);/* row's number cannot be decimal */
  var resetrow = document.createElement("STYLE");/* prepare to insert a style sheet */
  var rowstyle = document.createTextNode(".grid-container  { grid-template-columns:repeat(" + colnum + ",1fr);grid-template-rows: repeat(" + rows + ",auto);}");/* finalize the rules */
  resetrow.appendChild(rowstyle);/* insert the rules inside style tag*/
  document.head.appendChild(resetrow);/* insert the style tag inside head */
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*demo purpose*/

[data-table] {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--demo purpose-->
<div data-table>
  <p>reset numbers of columns </p>
  <button onclick="resetgrid(1)">1</button>
  <button onclick="resetgrid(2)">2</button>
  <button onclick="resetgrid(3)">3</button>
</div>
<!--end demo-->
<div id="gridrow" class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.two-columns{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using `grid-auto-flow:row;` it should ideally work. Here is a fiddle for the same. I have used your fiddle for the same and made changes to only one property.[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/689Lmrv4/3/)

Comment: @Arpir I need the items to flow in the column direction, not row direction.